# Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, f#

I have an application based on F#, and I use EF-Core and MySQL (Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).
I have an `async` method which updates data in DB(MySql)

```
let updatePlayerAchievementsAsync (logger:ILogger) (ctx:ReportCacheDbContext) (id: int) = async {
  let! account = ctx.AccountCaches.FirstOrDefaultAsync(fun e -> e.AccountId = id) |> Async.AwaitTask
  if account <> null then
    account.State <- "Closed"
    do! ctx.SaveChangesAsync true |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.Ignore
    logger.LogInformation("Account{0} updated", id)        
}
```

when this method comes to the 99th element, the following errors occurred:

```
|ERROR|System.InvalidOperationException:An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call. 
---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired. All pooled connections are in use.
```

I tried to follow 1st error's recomendation and tried to add `EnableRetryOnFailure()`

```
member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddOptions() |> ignore
    services.AddCors() |> ignore
    
    services
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            fun (service:IServiceProvider) (dbContext:DbContextOptionsBuilder) ->
                dbContext.UseMySql(profile.DbConnectionToAdmin /*HERE*/)|> ignore)
    ...
```

And I can't find any documentation about this adding options for F# & MySQL, cause all found info written on C#.
Maybe problem in used pools (default max=100) and I wrote next:

```
...
do! ctx.SaveChangesAsync true |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.Ignore
ctx.Database.CloseConnection()
logger.LogInformation("Account{0} updated", id)
```

But anyway problem wasn't solved.
This is my new experience in `F#` and `async` and I cant understand what I did incorrectly.
Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: The problem is in connection pooling, adding the retry mechanism won't help. The connections are leaking somewhere. How do you create the ``ReportCacheDbContext`` instance?

Comment: Btw what is the reason for calling ``SaveChangesAsync`` for each player, possibly 100+ times? The db context typically represents one business transaction (e.g. web request): You load the necessary data, make changes to objects, and finally call ``SaveChangesAsync`` once.

Comment: Method `updatePlayerAchievementsAsync` was executed in 15 parallel flows by using `ParallelContext` because this method takes very long time for execution. And `ReportCacheDbContext` located in other connected C# project which is intended for data migration by using `EF Core`. Instance `ReportCacheDbContext` created in next code `let ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ReportCacheDbContext>()`

Comment: I call `SaveChangesAsync` to save current row of data, if I wont do that during on the next row previous data wont be saved

Answer (score 14):

This was answered above with **UseSqlServer()** and this might be a bit confusing. It will work with **UseMySql()**, you just need to update your **Startup.cs** like below.

I tested and ran this against *Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version 5.0.0-alpha.2*

Adjust your maxRetryCount, maxRetryDelay etc to suit your needs.

```
        services.AddDbContextPool<DBContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(
                mySqlConnectionStr, 
                ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mySqlConnectionStr),
                options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 5,
                    maxRetryDelay: System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null)
                );
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFMiscellanous.ConnectionResiliency;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0",
            options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: And the answer isn't even about MySql.

Comment: but it is about EnableRetryOnFailure()

Comment: the above solution also works in case of MySql, tested it. thanks

Comment: how dafuq does this work for MySql? `UseSqlServer()` only works with MSSQL and if you try using `useMySql()` method like the op, you get an error cause its derived slightly differently and there is no method of `EnableRetryOnFailure()`, which is where this whole issue is coming from!!!???

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that this error is not always a retry error. In my case, I was changing the connection string for the database dynamically and I had given an incorrect database name. This database did not exist and I received that error. I'm working on a Web API application using C#, EF Core, and .Net 7.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34176219)